# Is there a task manager for Windows 7 that shows HDD activity in percent for every process (like in Windows 8)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, task-manager

I'm looking for a task manager for Windows 7 that shows which process is currently reading/writing on my HDD. I like how the Windows 8 and Windows 10 task manager shows the HDD activity in percent for every process.
Is there a custom task manager for Windows 7 that is also has this functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @fixer1234, Is it really an off topic question for this site?

Comment: @ali786: They're both worded as an off-topic question but could be edited to be on-topic.  Yeah, I agree with your suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is there and called as resource monitor..

After starting the task manager click on resource monitor it will display the disk activity over there.

see this for more info
http://www.7tutorials.com/how-use-resource-monitor-windows-7

Comment: Process Hacker 2 also has this ability.